# MVC mobile site as subdomain in Webforms site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing webforms project, and I want to add my new MVC4 (mobile-focussed) site to it, as a subdomain. I also want it to be able to access the session variables from the webforms site. The idea is that the user logs in on the webforms site, sets a session variable and gets redirected to the mobile site (on the subdomain).

Initially I have added my MVC site to the webforms site, by making changes to the web.config, global.asax (for routing etc.), Controllers, Views and other folders at root level. This allows me to access the session variables. However because the webforms site is well-established (old) there are implications to changing the web.config (least of all re-testing). Hence the need for a subdomain.

Is it as easy as dropping my MVC site's folder into the Webforms root, so it has its own web.config, and changing the global.asax to route to it (and then creating a subdomain)? Will I still be able to access the session variables in the subdomain?

Comment: Rather than a dedicated mobile site, why not embrace [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. It is a responsive site - works on all devices with bootstrap 3, but it will be primarily accessed via mobile (we are replacing an ios app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share the session, I implemented this from Microsoft. It is a HttpModule.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527105

There was some additional work to do - I felt this article assumes you know a little about IIS. For example I had to manually add the module using IIS Manager.

I managed to get it to work in IIS7 by manually adding the Module using IIS Manager.

(Open IIS Manager -> select the application -> click modules (top right) -> add the SharedSessionModule by clicking 'Add managed module'.

```
Name: SharedSessionModule
Type: <namespace>.SharedSessionModule
```

(a dialog box said it could not find the assembly but at runtime it was fine)

Then Restart IIS.

The problem I then had was "session state is not available in this context" when serving up non-page items like images, .pdfs etc. Before I solved this, I have been asked to use my initial method (side-by-side) so I have not found how to change this BUT there are many suggestions on SO and other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project for the MVC mobile, configure the domain binding in IIS in something like that *m.mydomain.com*.
In the web.config of the two you define the same main domain:

```
<httpCookies domain=".mydomain.com"/>
```

Here start the difficoult task, you need to play attention to share the same `machineKey` in the two projects and probably you need to add an HttpModule depending on the selected session scenario.

Take a look on this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527105) that can help you on some guidance.